# Automatically scale an image to match text height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've got an image which I want to use inline with some text, but I need it to match the text height. I know it's possible to something like `<img src="img.jpg" height=16>` or even `<img src="img.jpg" height="100%">`, but the former does not scale with text size and the latter seems to make it the size of the div, not the text height. Can anyone help?

Example HTML:

```
<body>
This is a test <img src="img.jpg">
</body>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: CSS cannot do this for you. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: :D I guess that's why this question is tagged as JavaScript

Comment: I can use javascript, i didn't know if it was required.

Comment: Try wrapping the text with `span` or something then  get the `$('span').outerHeight(true)` with (jquery) of it and do the trick.

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML that you're using?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

#### Did you try this giving the image height as 1em?

```
img {height: 1em;}
```

#### Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yAr7z/

Comment: Works great, though I needed to use 0.8em. Thanks!

Comment: `1ex` or similar should work even better across fonts - it will match the *height* of lowercase text.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Here is the inline tag: <img [...] style="height:1ex;" />